# Ionic 4 : Problem with Statusbar overflow content

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

I have a little problem with my app, the `StatusBar` doesn't show properly as you can see :

[image]

I declared the `StatusBar` with `Statusbar plugin` : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/

In **app.component.ts**

```
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
this.statusBar.show();
```

Can I set a custom `padding-top` for all my `pages` and the `menu` ?
Or is it a properly method to show the `statusbar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app.component.ts**

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

**pages.ts**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false); 
    this.statusBar.show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### METHOD 1

You can add **padding-top** to `ion-toolbar` inside **variable.scss**

### METHOD 2

you can change your status bar color, give same color as your header color.

```
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false)
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.styleLightContent(); //Status bar color, light if you have dark header
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('HERE YOUR CUSTOM COLOR VALUE');
```

Comment: And you know what value i can set ? 
Depending on platform and screen size ?

Comment: i can tell you wich is the correct way. but if you want to keep this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true); My method will not work. editing my answer...

Comment: i have situation, that it works only when the app is open, when i close the app without shutting down , i dont see the status bar